# Combine results in one row from multiple rows based on criteria from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which contains student grades (SAG).  I need to show all grades that aren't `NULL` or `''` from one row based on `ID` and `ResultGroup` and have all other grades coming from another row based on `ID` and `ResultGroup` in the same table.

```
TABLE - SAG

ID     RESULTGROUP     GRADE
-----------------------------
102    AC              C
102    ACPJ            B
124    AC              A
124    ACPJ            
242    AC              B
242    ACPJ            
101    AC              D
101    ACPJ            C
```

What I'm trying to work out is how to get the results from ResultGroup `ACPJ` and only those from ResultGroup `AC` if there is a `NULL` or `''` in the Grade for that `ID`.

END RESULT?  Something like...

```
SAG_COMBINED

ID     FinalGrade
-----------------
102    B
124    A
242    B
101    C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT acpj.ID
   , CASE
        WHEN acpj.Grade IS NULL OR acpj.Grade = '' THEN ac.Grade
        ELSE acpj.Grade
     END AS FinalGrade
FROM SAG AS acpj
INNER JOIN SAG AS ac ON acpj.ID = ac.ID
WHERE acpj.ResultGroup = 'ACPJ'
   AND ac.ResultGroup = 'AC'
```

Comment: While this is more compact, the `JOIN` only works if there is a row for every `RESULTGROUP` for every `ID` involved, which has not been specified in the question.

Comment: You are correct. I made this assumption when the Grade for ResultGroup could be NULL, though it is a good point.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Adam, tested and all okay.  Been thrown into this work and am only starting to swim!